# Easier way to write this: if (routine !== null && routine.exercises !== undefined && routine.exercises.length > 0)

Tags: javascript

Is there a easier way to do this is JavaScript:

```
    if (routine !== null && routine.exercises !== undefined && routine.exercises.length > 0) {
        // Do Something
    }
```

In Dart for example I could just do this:

```
    if (routine?.exercises?.length > 0 ?? 0) {
        // DO Something
    }
```

Which means if routine is null or routine.exercises is null or routine.exercises.length is not greater 0, then just take 0 as expression

Comment: `if (routine && routine.exercises && routine.exercises.length)`

Comment: `if (routine && routine.hasExercises())`... this is why we refactor.

Comment: Oh and https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
if (routine && routine.exercises && routine.exercises.length) ...
```

or shorter, but might be harder to read, use default values

```
if (((routine || {}).exercises || []).length) ...
```

Example:

```js
function test(routine) {
  if (routine && routine.exercises && routine.exercises.length) {
    console.log('passed with', JSON.stringify(routine));
  }
  if (((routine || {}).exercises || []).length) {
    console.log('passed with', JSON.stringify(routine));
  }
}

test({ exercises: [1] });
test({});
test(undefined);
```

Comment: While default values are handy, IMO it's cluttered and harder to maintain/reason about.

Comment: @Dave Newton, I agree, it can be harder to read due to the parenthesis and or operator, but less repetitive at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`0` `undefined` and `null` all are falsy values you don't need to compare just direclty put them.

```
if (routine && routine.exercises && routine.exercises.length) {
        // Do Something
}
```